# My brilliant attempt at humour!

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, humor

??&T

Who’s On ?????

We ??????? the excessive use of force

??? World In Data

???? (online retailer)

Apologies for my ?????? attempt at humour!

?????? me

Smoking is bad ??? you

?????????? Is Awesome

Roger ????

A spelling error ??????? this clue

Fiegenbaum ????????

???????? numbers

????? release

ANSWER = ???????

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost all of the correct words to insert have been suggested in other users' answers, just not all together. However, I believe the true combination is:

> [**AT**&T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T)<sup>1</sup>
>  [Who’s On **FIRST**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTcRRaXV-fg)<sup>2</sup>
>  We **CONDEMN** the excessive use of force<sup>2</sup>
>  [**OUR** World In Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_World_in_Data)<sup>1</sup>
>  [**VERY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_(online_retailer)) (online retailer)<sup>@Stiv</sup>
>  Apologies for my **FEEBLE** attempt at humour!<sup>@OP</sup>
>  **EXCUSE** me<sup>1</sup>
>  Smoking is bad **FOR** you<sup>1</sup>
>  [**EVERYTHING** Is Awesome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StTqXEQ2l-Y)<sup>1</sup>
>  Roger **THAT**<sup>1</sup>
>  A spelling error **FOLLOWS** this clue<sup>@OP</sup> (since 'Fiegenbaum' should be spelled 'F**ei**genbaum')
>  [Fiegenbaum **CONSTANT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants)<sup>1</sup>
>  **NEGATIVE** numbers<sup>3</sup>
>  **PRESS** release<sup>3</sup>
>
>  <sup>1 First found by @QuantumTwinkie</sup>
>  <sup>2 First found by @tmpearce</sup>
>  <sup>3 First found by @Bewilderer</sup>

This yields:

> A cryptic crossword clue! **AT FIRST CONDEMN OUR VERY FEEBLE EXCUSE FOR EVERYTHING THAT FOLLOWS CONSTANT NEGATIVE PRESS**.

How do we interpret this?

> 'At first' implies we need to take the first letters of the words which follow, and this will yield a word 'THAT FOLLOWS CONSTANT NEGATIVE PRESS'. The initials of the words in between spell the answer: **COVFEFE**!

This is of course a reference to:

> A very famous [mis-tweet](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/may/31/what-is-covfefe-donald-trump-baffles-twitter-post) by President Donald Trump of the USA, in which he tweeted to his millions of followers:
>
>  ***"Despite the constant negative press covfefe"***
>
>  (See how 'covfefe' quite literally *follows* the words 'constant negative press' here?)
>
>  Still nobody truly knows what he meant to say, although many people suspected he hadn't yet had his morning covfefe, so it's no wonder it came out wrong!

Comment: This is pretty much correct - you got the general gist! A few more details (rot13):

(1) Svrtraonhz vf n qryvorengr reebe, urapr gur cerivbhf pyhr fubhyq or SBYYBJF abg RSSRPGF
(2) V vagraqrq SRROYR ohg SNVYRQ vf rdhnyyl inyvq
(3) Pbisrsr sbyybjf pbafgnag artngvir cerff fb gung zrnaf jr unir n cresrpgyl inyvq pelcgvp pyhr rira gubhtu abobql xabjf jung gur jbeq zrnaf!

Comment: @happystar Aha! That typo now makes perfect sense! Nice touch :) Will fix!

Comment: Writing in June 2021, where rot13(Ovqra vf cerfvqrag abj: "pbisrsr" vf abj trarenyyl haqrefgbbq gb unir zrnag "pbirentr".)

Answer (score 7):

> WE.....................??&T  ([Water Environment & Techonology](https://www.wef.org/resources/publications/all-magazines/water-environment-technology/))
>
>     FIRST.................Who’s On ????? ([Abbott and Costello](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTcRRaXV-fg))
>
>     CONDEMN.........We ??????? the excessive use of force
>
>     OUR....................??? World In Data ([ourworldindata.org](https://ourworldindata.org/))
>
>     LAME..................???? ([online retailer](https://www.lame.store/))
>
>     FAILED...............Apologies for my ?????? attempt at humour!
>
>     EXCUSE.............?????? me
>
>     FOR...................Smoking is bad ??? you
>
>     EVERYTHING...?????????? Is Awesome ([So say the LEGOs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StTqXEQ2l-Y))
>
>     THAT..................Roger ????
>
>     DEFIES..............A spelling error ??????? this clue
>
>     CONSTANT........Fiegenbaum ???????? ([From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feigenbaum_constants)
>
>     RATIONAL.........???????? numbers
>
>     EARLY................????? release (Could also be FIRST, like first release of software etc., with little change in meaning)
>
>
>     ------
>     ANSWER = [ANSWERS | GUESSES | etc]

Comment: Doesn't the answer have to be 7 letters?

Comment: Good catch @Ilak. There are options for that... I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Maybe (rot 13) "pnhgvba" bg "npgvbaf"? Neither of those fit quite as well as your original answer, though.

Comment: what about (rot 13) NGGRZCG? for the last one?

Answer (score 4):

**Partial**

??&T

> At

Who’s On ?????

> Next

We ??????? the excessive use of force

> Protest

??? World In Data

> Our

???? (online retailer)

> Ebay or Etsy

Apologies for my ?????? attempt at humour!

> Working on this. Maybe a 6 letter word for "brilliant" as the title suggests.

?????? me

> Excuse?

Smoking is bad ??? you

> For

?????????? Is Awesome

> Everything

Roger ????

> That

A spelling error ??????? this clue

> Inside(s)? Maybe it is a word spelled incorrect.

Fiegenbaum ????????

> Constant

???????? numbers

> Rational?

????? release

> Early

Total

> At Next Protest our .....

Answer (score 2):

Partial

> AT
> FIRST
> CONDEMN
> OUR
> WISH
> FAILED
> ??????
> FOR
> EVERYTHING
> THAT
> ???????
> CONSTANT
> NEGATIVE
> PRESS
>
> ANSWER = ???????